# Replacement of static sub-strings in SQL Strings with constant date Strings

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have got a piece of software which has in-built code processor and support the shell scripting.I have multiple SQL strings in a file which will be processed through the software one-by-one and values of certain sub-string constants will be overridden by that software without changing the original file which contains the original SQLs.you can pass the replacement parameters at runtime to that software.

Below is the example sed for one of the SQLs:

```
echo " select * from TABLE where   DATE(TSP_DATE) between (CURRENT DATE -1 DAY) AND (CURRENT DATE)" | sed -e 's/CURRENT DATE - 1 DAY/'08/30/2018'/; s CURRENT DATE/'08/31/2018'/
```

I want to replace sub-strings

> CURRENT DATE - 1 DAY

with '08/30/2018' and

> CURRENT DATE

with '08/31/2018' using one command. Date Strings include the quotes.

When I ran the above script,I got below error :

> sed: -e expression #1,char 29: unknown option to 's'

Regards,
Ankit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, if you want to implement a solution, that's more complicated than necessary.

Whatever DBMS you're using, I'm pretty sure it has a function for the current date. So you don't have to do this in your shell script.

For example, when you use MySQL, you can simply use this query:

```
select * from TABLE where DATE(TSP_DATE) between CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURDATE();
```

---

When you want to do it with sed anyway, you can do it like this:

```
echo "select * from TABLE where   DATE(TSP_DATE) between (CURRENT DATE -1 DAY) AND (CURRENT DATE)" | sed "s#CURRENT DATE -1 DAY#'08/30/2018'#;s#CURRENT DATE#'08/31/2018'#"
```

As delimiter you can choose whatever you want. When you choose something other than `/` you don't have to escape it all the time, when you use it in your replacement string.